# Muti-core parallel computing over a for loop in python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a simple `for` loop which is to print a number from 1 to 9999 with 5 seconds sleep in between. The code is as below:

```
import time

def run():
    length = 10000
    for i in range(1, length):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(5)
run()
```

I want to apply `multiprocessing` to run the for loop concurrently with multi-cores. So I amended the code above to take 5 cores:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def run():
    length = 10000
    for i in range(1, length):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = mp.Pool(5)
        p.map(run())
        p.close()
```

There is no issue in running the job but it seems like it is not running in parallel with 5 cores. How could I get the code worked as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are running the same `1..9999` loop 5 times, and second, you are executing the `run` function instead of passing it to the `.map()` method.

You must prepare your queue before passing it to the `Pool` instance so that all 5 workers process the same queue:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def run(i):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = 10000
    queue = range(1, length)
    p = mp.Pool(5)
    p.map(run, queue)
    p.close()
```

Note that it will process the numbers out of order as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map). For example, worker #1 will process `1..500`, worker #2 will process `501..1000` etc:

> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.

If you want to process the numbers *more similarly* to the single threaded version, set `chunksize` to `1`:

```
p.map(run, queue, 1)
```